# Which data type maps to MySQL's bit(1)?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I want to create a `struct` to represent a DB model using `Go` with `gorm`.
I have a table with records that have a field of type `bit(1)` which represents a binary value (0 or 1).

How can i make sure it doesn't "conflict" with my Go struct definition? I guess using `bool` as a type is not the correct answer?

Comment: There's no `bit` type in Go, you'll have to choose from the primitives that are [builtin](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/).

Comment: But then won't i get an error, for example, when i would try to put the value `1` into a field that's defined as `bool`?

Comment: ... using `bool` directly I would say is incorrect, or at the least confusing, however you can declare a new type from `bool`, have that new type implement the Valuer and Scanner interfaces to properly translate the values between the app and db layers . Additionally you may also want to declare constants to represent `0` and `1` and use those constants instead of the `0` and `1`.

Comment: from https://godoc.org/database/sql#Rows.Scan `For scanning into *bool, the source may be true, false, 1, 0, or string inputs parseable by strconv.ParseBool.` Check out the strconv.ParseBool function. Putting `1` into a bool field will translate just fine. We do this without any problems (so far). I know that the `gorm` package auto migrate command represents bools as bit(1) by default  for at least one databse system so it seems like a popular convention